# Getting JSON parameter from requests, I get: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to get a parameter from a JSON string loaded with requests.

I think I tried any combination I can think of.

Any hints are very appreciated.

My code is this:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json_string = r.json
status = json.dumps(json_string['httpStatusCode'])
```

and I'm getting

```
'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: it is `r.json()` , in second line

Comment: Totally unrelated, but why `json.dumps()` in the last line ???

Comment: Not sure. I'll tjeck if it can be omitted

Comment: Having to call parameterless methods with () is still a gotcha for me in Python, coming from Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are getting because you are assigning a "method" object to json_string.
Since in python "method" objects are not subscriptable.
To get JSON response you have to do this

```
json_string = r.json()
```